# have sed translate both cases from lowercase input

Tags: sed

I have variables `from="abc"` and `to="xyz"` defining lowercase strings.

How can I use `sed` so that it replaces `from` by `to`, but matching the case.

That is `echo "abc def ABC DEF" | <sedcommand>`

should produce `xyz def XYZ DEF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a combination of sed and bash parameter expansion:

```
$ from="abc" to="xyz" 
$ echo "abc def ABC DEF" | sed "s/$from/$to/g; s/$from/${to^^}/Ig"
xyz def XYZ DEF
```

The first `s///` replaces any lowercase instances, the second replaces any mixed case with uppercase -- will replace `Abc` with `XYZ`

Comment: @mitchus, I forgot the `g` flag, you'll want that

Comment: Nice! To touch only "pure cases": `sed "s/$from/$to/g; s/${from^^}/${to^^}/g"`